# AJAX not sending Form Data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I' sending some form data to PHP via AJAX. The value of the input field is being displayed before the data is sent using AJAX, but in the PHP script the value received is NULL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#my_form').submit(function(){    
        event.preventDefault();                 
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);                    
        $.ajax({            
            url: "signup.php",
            enctype: "multipart/form-data",
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){ 
                //do something
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               // some alert
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    //.......
    $fname=$_POST['fname']; 
    $lname=$_POST['lname']; 
    //.......
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="my_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="inputname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="inputname" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="BUTTON" class="submitbtn">
</form>
```

I get some Undefined index:fname warning

Comment: Show complete code. Your form mainly.

Comment: why you dont use serialize() ??

Comment: What are you returning your data as? JSON? What is the value of response in success?

Comment: I just echo values such as 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#my_form').submit(function(){    
        event.preventDefault();   
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({            
            url: "signup.php",            
            cache: false,
            type: "post",            
            data: data,            
            success: function(response){ 
                //do something
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               // some alert
            }
        });
    });
});

<?php   
    $fname=$_POST['fname']; 
    $lname=$_POST['lname']; 
    echo $fname;
    echo $lname;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `enctype` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  This is the default for forms that don't specify an encoding type, like yours.

Comment: I did ... but still data is not passed to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#my_form').submit(function(event){    
        event.preventDefault();                 
        var fname= $(this).find('#fname').val();
        var lname= $(this).find('#lname').val();                
        $.ajax({            
            url: "signup.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {fname:fname , lname:lname},
            success: function(response){ 
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               // some alert
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in php

```
<?php
    //.......
    $fname=$_POST['fname']; 
    $lname=$_POST['lname']; 
    echo $fname .|||. $lname;
    //.......
?>
```

Comment: I get "Undefined index:fname
Undefined index:lname" in my php

Comment: Serializing the data helped. At first i didn't serialize the data cuz i had sign_in form and it works fine without serialization....so i wanted to know what i was doig wrong with this sign_up form.....any way thanks for the comment above